# Matrix differentiation with respect to the middle matrix

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I have $\alpha = w'B'x$, where $\alpha$ is a scalar, and $w$, $B$, and $x$ are vectors or matrices with the following dimensions (the prime denotes transpose):

- $w_{(k-1) * 1}$
- $B_{p * (k-1)}$
- $x_{p*1}$

How do I take the derivative with respect to $B$? That is, how do I simplify $\dfrac{\partial \alpha}{\partial B}$?

Context: I am trying to solve a minimization problem with respect to $B$, so I need to take the first derivative. The minimization problem is $argmin_B \dfrac{(R-w'B'x)^2}{f(x)}$.

Comment: If you have a expression like $\alpha = w^T B x = \sum_{i,j} w_i B_{ij} x_j$ then $\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial B_{ij}} = w_i x_j$ since the expression is linear in the matrix elements $B_{ij}$.

Comment: @UtilityMaximiser so would $\dfrac{\partial \alpha}{\partial B}$ be a matrix where each $i, j$ index is $w_i x_j$? What would be the dimensions of this matrix?

Comment: Yes if $\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial B}$ is interpreted as the gradient of the function $B \mapsto w^T B x$. You could also view $\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial B}$ as a vector with $(k-1) p$ entries.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\a{\alpha}\def\b{\beta}\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$Use a colon to denote the matrix inner product,
which is a convenient notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
Treating vectors as rectangular matrices $(n=1)$
this corresponds to the usual dot product
$$\eqalign{
a:b \;=\; a\cdot b \;=\; a^Tb \\
}$$
Write the $\a$ function using this notation, then calculate its differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
\a &= wx^T:B \\
d\a &= wx^T:dB \\
\grad{\a}{B} &= wx^T \\\\
}$$
Note that the properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in the matrix inner product to be rearranged in several different ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
C:AB &= A^TC:B = CB^T:A \\
}$$

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, if you want to take the derivative of a tensor $T$ of rank $k$ w.r.t. another tensor $X$ of rank $l$, the derivative can be encoded in a rank $k+l$ tensor

$$ \frac{{\rm d} T}{{\rm d} X} 
= \Big(\frac{{\rm d} T_{\mathbf i}}{{\rm d} X_{\mathbf j}}\Big)_{\mathbf i, \mathbf j} $$

Where $\mathbf i, \mathbf j$ are appropriate multi-indices. (Ignoring upper/lower index distinction for simplicity)

Now, given vectors $u\in\mathbb R^m$, $v\in\mathbb R^n$ consider the function $$f\colon \mathbb R^{m\times n}\to\mathbb R, A\mapsto u^T \cdot A \cdot v = \sum_{kl} A_{kl} u_k v_l$$ Then, by the definition above $f'(A)$ can be expressed as

$$ 
\frac{{\rm d} u^T A v}{{\rm d} A} 
= \Big( \frac{\sum_{kl} A_{kl} u_k v_l}{{\rm d}A_{ij}}  \Big)_{ij}
= ( u_i v_j)_{ij} = uv^T
$$

Which encodes a linear function $\mathbb R^{m\times n}\to\mathbb R$ via $X\mapsto \langle f'(A), X\rangle = \langle uv^T, X\rangle = u^T X v$, where $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$ is the [natural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_Hilbert_spaces) ([Frobenius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product)) inner product on $\mathbb R^{m\times n}$. This is of course just an instance of [Riesz' representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem), which tells us that any linear function $\mathbb R^{m\times n}\to\mathbb R$ can be expressed as $X\mapsto \langle V, X\rangle$ for some matrix $V$.

Answer (score -1):

$\alpha$ is a linear map with respect to $B$. Therefore, its derivative at any point is $\alpha$  itself.

So here

$$\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial B}\cdot H= w^\prime H^\prime x$$ where I imagine you use the prime to denote the transpose.

Comment: Would you mind adding details to this solution? For example, say we have a linear map, $f$, where $f(x)=x$. Then my counterexample would be $f'(x)= 1 \neq f(x)$.

Comment: Remember that the **derivative map** at $x_0$ for a real map is the map $h \mapsto f^\prime(x_0)h$. Which for $f(x)=x$ is $h \mapsto f^\prime(x)h=h$. Exactly the initial map. I’ll update my answer with more details.

Comment: Downvoter, a comment is required !

Comment: Could you explain if this answer is at odds with the comment from UtilityMaximiser?

Comment: @bob You have to make your mind on an important thing! Either you speak of the derivative, which is your initial question and coherent with your notation; in which case my answer is the right one. Or you expect not the derivative, but the gradient; in which case , you have to look at UtilityMaximiser comment. **The gradient is not the derivative !**